# Calculate Gunning-Fog score on excel values

Tags: python, pandas, readability

I have a spreadsheet with fields containing a body of text.

[image]

I want to calculate the Gunning-Fog score on each row and have the value output to that same excel file as a new column. To do that, I first need to calculate the score for each row. The code below works if I hard key the text into the `df` variable. However, it does not work when I define the field in the sheet (i.e., `rfds`) and pass that through to my r variable. I get the following error, but two fields I am testing contain 3,896 and 4,843 words respectively.

```
readability.exceptions.ReadabilityException: 100 words required.
```

Am I missing something obvious? Disclaimer, I am very new to python and coding in general! Any help is appreciated.

```
from readability import Readability
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:/Users/name/edgar/test/item1a_sandbox.xls")

rfd = df["Item 1A"]
rfds = rfd.to_string() # to fix "TypeError: expected string or buffer"

r = Readability(rfds)
fog = r.gunning_fog()
print(fog.score)
```

Comment: Once you've read data into your df, refer to it with .loc or .iloc. At the moment you're passing a column reference which will is likely either the length or the reference name.

Comment: Thanks @Alan. So, if I understand correctly, I am referring to the df in the `rfd` line? From what I understand, referring to the df with iloc represents the specific rows and columns. So, if I want to identify `rfd` as rows 2 and 3 of column 3, I would write `rfd = df.iloc[1:3, 3]` correct? When I do that, I still get the same error.

Comment: You're still using a column ('series' in pandas speak). Assuming `df["Item 1A"]` is getting the column correctly, what you have is a one column set of rows of text. You need to iterate over those rows to get the values individually (You can - and I'll leave this as a separate exercise, use something like `apply` to generate a column of readability scores in one go. That's a bit advanced for now though). Use either `iterrows` or `itertuple`to go through the column. It's been a while - it's something like `for index, row in rfd.iterrows(): print(row.loc[0])`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your willingness to help. I am having a hard time weaving this into my code, and it is definitely a result of my lack of knowledge/experience. I will keep researching. When I add the for loop, I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'`. Also, I confirmed that `df["Item 1A"]` is getting the correct column by `rfd.head()`

Comment: If `iterrows` isn't available for a Series object, then skip generating the series. Go straight to `for index, row in df.iterrows(): print(row.loc[2])`

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am now getting a new error. `raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You need to pass the cell value and are currently passing a column of cells.

This line `rfd = df["Item 1A"]` returns a reference to a column. `rfd.to_string()` then generates a string containing either length (number of rows in the column) or the column reference. This is why a `TypeError` was thrown - neither the length nor the reference are strings.

Rather than taking a column and going down it, approach it from the other direction. Take the rows and then pull out the column:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row.iloc[2])
```

The [2] is the column index.

Now a cell identifier exists, this can be passed to the Readability calculator:

```
    r = Readability(row.iloc[2])
    fog = r.gunning_fog()
    print(fog.score)
```

Note that these can be combined together into one command:

```
    print(Readability(row.iloc[2]).gunning_fog())
```

This shows you how commands can be chained together - which way you find it easier is up to you. The chaining is useful when you give it to something like `apply` or `applymap`.

Putting the whole thing together (the step by step way):

```
from readability import Readability
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:/Users/name/edgar/test/item1a_sandbox.xls")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    r = Readability(row.iloc[2])
    fog = r.gunning_fog()
    print(fog.score)
```

Or the clever way:

```
from readability import Readability
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:/Users/name/edgar/test/item1a_sandbox.xls")

print(df["Item 1A"].apply(lambda x: Readability(x).gunning_fog()))
```